# Can't find PayPal SetExpressCheckout Method

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, paypal, wsdl

Trying to implement PayPal's Express Checkout using SOAP.  I've imported the .wsdl listed on their site.  Documentation says to call the SetExpressCheckout Method, however I can't find that anywhere.  I've check the Reference.cs but don't see it there either.  I've looked in all the following classes with near matching names but no dice.

```
    SetExpressCheckoutRequest aaa= new SetExpressCheckoutRequest();
    SetExpressCheckoutRequestType bbb = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
    SetExpressCheckoutReq ccc= new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
    SetExpressCheckoutResponse ddd = new SetExpressCheckoutResponse();
    SetExpressCheckoutResponseType eee = new SetExpressCheckoutResponseType();
    GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType fff  = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType();
```

Under what class does this exist?  
wsdl version="124.0" 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer - haven't used the Paypal SOAP API for quite some time*

Just did a `wsdl` to generate proxy classes on that resource and can see: `PayPalAPIAASoapBinding` has a method `SetExpressCheckout`

- that expects a `SetExpressCheckoutReq` parameter, and will return
- `SetExpressCheckoutResponseType` containg the `token`

Hth...